# Parameters in ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

In migrating a Vanilla MVC project to a Vanilla Umbraco project, i am facing a couple of issues. One of them is with the query parameters, and transferring them to my Index.

Old ActionResult from working MVC project:

```
public ActionResult Index(int value1, int value2, bool value3 = false)
{...}
```

New ActionResult, working in a Vanilla Umbraco project

```
public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
{...}
```

But i need the parameters (coming from querystring) from the original project.
I tried simply adding them:

```
public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model, int value1, int value2, bool value3 = false)
{...}
```

But when i do the latter, i get the error `'Controller.Index(RenderModel, int, int, bool): no suitable method found to override'`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass those values as parameters. You should extract them from query string instead.

```
public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
{
     var value1 = Request["value1"];
     var value2 = Request["value2"];
     var value3 = Request["value3"];
     ...
}
```

Comment: Why is that? (when it worked in the vanilla MVC project)

Comment: That's because when you have DocType controller in umbraco it behaves differently then regular mvc controller.

Answer (score 0):

That error means not all parameters got loaded as they should. Just make them all accept null as value, and check on what you get during the call.

```
public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model, int? value1, int? value2, bool value3 = false)
{...}
```